# how to restrict ONLY space and special characters to be entered in the input texbox. We need to allow both when entered with alphabets

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Expected Results :- It should not accept only empty space or special characters.
But when entered with alphabets and it should accept all characters and space.

```
           <div>
            <div className={createNewContainerStyles}>
                <p>Reason</p>
                <TextArea value={reason} placeholder='Add reason' showCount maxLength={250} onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
                    setReason(e.target.value)
                }}>
                </TextArea>
                <div>
                  <Button type="default" 
                          loading={loading} 
                          onClick={onClose}>Cancel
                  </Button>
                  <Button type="primary" disabled={!reason} loading={loading} onClick={onBlacklistRequest}>Add
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In my use-case, I came up with logic that: only condition in which Disabled shall be false is the input must contain an alphabetic character, rest in all conditions (empty,  null, only blank spaces, only special character) Disable shall be true.

` const validator2 = () => {

            if(reason.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/)){

                return true;

            } else {

            return false;

            }

        } `

Tried creating this function, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:** Check whether String contains Alphabets or not. If String only contains special characters or spaces throw an error, and if a string has alphabets then there is no need to check for spaces and special characters.

**Here:** I have used regex to check the string.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [reason, setReason] = useState("");

  const verifyInput = (value) => {
    // Check String contain alphanumeric characters or not
    if(/[a-zA-Z]/g.test(value)){
        setReason(value);
    } else {
        // Handle Erorr
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Reason</p>
      <textarea
        value={reason}
        placeholder="Add reason"
        maxLength={250}
        onChange={(e) => verifyInput(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to @gadgetvala's answer, you can use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute (for `input` elements):

```html
<div>
    <div className={createNewContainerStyles}>
        <p>Reason</p>
        <input type="text" value={reason} pattern="^[a-zA-Z][^$]+" placeholder='Add reason' showCount maxLength={250} onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
            setReason(e.target.value)
        }}/>
        <div>
            <Button type="default" loading={loading} onClick={onClose}>Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button type="primary" disabled={!reason} loading={loading} onClick={onBlacklistRequest}>Add
            </Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Error :- "Property 'pattern' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextAreaProps & RefAttributes<TextAreaRef>'."